# getLoginURL Redirecting outside of iFrame, won't return to App Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating my first test app on the new Facebook API, and sadly many of the examples I've seen before include deprecated code. I'm following the typical examples to authenticate someone, and then redirect them back to the app on successful authentication.

Even though I'm specifying a 'next' param with the URL to my app canvas, it always automatically redirects to the app on my server (outside of the iFrame). Even when omitting next, this seems to be the default behavior (it will not allow me to specify the app URL as the redirect_uri, says it's not owned by the app and can't use it as a valid URL).

Here is my code as it is now:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'config.php';
    /*  Get valid session */
    //$session = $facebook->getSession();
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user=null;
        }

    }

    if($user) {
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/fgdeveloper','fbconnect'=>0,'scope'=>'read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos'));
        echo '<script>top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
        break;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I want to mention that after examining the behavior of 2 other apps, they seem to redirect outside FB to the host server, and then back to the app page on FB. I was able to acheive this by forcing a redirect from my server if a session/successful auth existed - but wondering if this is the right way to do it? I'm still curious as to why the auth process wouldn't handle this based on params to getLoginURL?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=135904836523042&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grooveyorkcity.com%2FTestFBApp%2F&response_type=code&state=05be7caaa1842c9d69d7b0a44f4da61e&fbconnect=1&perms=read_stream%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_photos

You can see that the `next=` goes to your web server rather than to the canvas url.  I also noticed you don't have SSL configured.

Something is misconfigured in app settings or your app.  Check to see where you told it to use grooveyorkcity.com and change it to https://apps.facebook.com/fgdeveloper/postauthlandingpage.htm or some such. Don't forget to set your https (SSL) url as well so your app is fully compliant.

Comment: Hi DMCS: Thanks for this. Just experimenting with my account, so will be definitely implementing SSL in a real world situation. I see what you're saying above, just can't figure out why 'next' is not obeying. I read a post on a different site that states a bug with the PHP SDK, related to how it merges default params with specified ones (in this case, no matter what I specify for next it uses something else). I checked my app settings and the only place the URL is specified is in the Canvas URL, which it's supposed to be. Everything else checks out. Thoughts?

Comment: Where do you have that link to grooveyourcity.com defined?  Maybe as a workaround you can use the Javascript SDK's FB.login() call.

Comment: The only place I can see it defined is in the actual App setup in the developer console - the Canvas URL. Otherwise there is no other place. I read somewhere this may be a bug in the PHP SDK due to improper merging of params and default values. The way I'm getting around it now is to redirect from my server back to the app page on FB. I will try the JS SDK and see if that fares better - thanks!